# Constraining returned value decimal places in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I am looking for some help.
I am running the following in mySQL

```
"SELECT AVG(`readingValue`) AS `readingValue` FROM table
```

This returns the value - 0.0282982

If possible I would like to return only 4 digits rounded up/down to closest. 
In this case 0.0283.

Is this possible in the select string, or will I need to do it in php?

p.s `readingValue` column is float(4,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the [ROUND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function be an option?

```
SELECT ROUND( AVG(`readingValue`), 4 ) AS `readingValue` FROM table
```